# Android Network Security Config Allow Any IP

Tags: android, ionic-framework, android-network-security-config

Device can't call any local IP's without them being declared in network config eg. http://192.168.0.101

```
<domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
  <domain>
    192.168.0.101
  </domain>
  <domain>
    etc.
  </domain>
</domain-config>
```

I've created an application that requires devices to chat over the local network without accessing the internet. When an HTTP call is made to the devices IP Addresses it fails because the IP was not declared in the network config. It would be impossible to declare every single possible IP. Help? How do I get around this?

Comment: set android:allowClearUserData="true" in the application tag of your android manifest

Comment: @petyr I added the manifest tag `<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="org.apache.cordova" android:versionName="1.0" android:versionCode="1" android:allowClearUserData="true">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" />
</manifest>` Is this correct?

Comment: no, you should put it in the <application /> tag